# Error al compilar mi proyecto de flutter parseDebugLibraryResources

Tags: flutter

**ALGUIEN QUE ME AYUDE A SOLUCIONARLO**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':location:parseDebugLibraryResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':location:androidApis'.
> Failed to transform file 'android.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}
> > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar.
> > C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)

Comment: ¿Es tu primer proyecto em Flutter? publica los resultados de flutter doctor

Answer (score 0):

¿Es capaz de construir si se añade cualquier otra dependencia de geolocator, locationy permission_handler?
¿Puedes intentarlo flutter pub cache repairy luego flutter runver si funciona? Detenga la instancia de la aplicación primero y luego pruebe los comandos anteriores.
¿Puedes crear un nuevo proyecto de Flutter y luego intentar agregar estos complementos nuevamente y ver si funciona?

Revisa este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54244959/failure-build-failed-with-an-exception-in-flutter/54248935#54248935) parece que puede solventarte el problema

Comment: Gracias, pero no me funciona, mire el link y no dan solucion tampoco